# Why is my "Event" always null?

Tags: c#

I am trying to wire up a new event, but for some reason "Changed" is always evaluating to null

```
    public class MyTreeViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
        private MyTreeViewItem _parent;

        public MyTreeViewItem(MyTreeViewItem parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        private bool _checked;
        public bool Checked
        {
            get
            {
                return _checked;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _checked)
                {
                    _checked = value;
                    OnChanged("test");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler Changed;

        public ObservableCollection<MyTreeViewItem> Children { get; set; }

    // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
    protected virtual void OnChanged(string test)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, null);
    }
```

**Subscribing code (PropertyChanged Works, Changed does not)**

```
_playgroupTree = new MyTreeViewItem(null);
AddChildNodes(4, ref _playgroupTree);
_playgroupTree.Changed += new EventHandler(_playgroupTree_Changed);
_playgroupTree.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_playgroupTree_PropertyChanged);
```

Is really weird because I am also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (which works), and this code is almost exactly the same (I have tried using the same deligate type, but still it does not work.

I have been using this website as a reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: You probably subscribed to the wrong object.

Comment: I think the issue might be that my class is hierarchical in nature. and the event will always apply to a child element, and never the root.

Comment: Have confirmed can directly wire up a specific node _playgroupTree.Children[0].Changed += new EventHandler(ReportingView_Changed);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, you haven't shown any code subscribing to the event. Where do you have code like this:

```
YourClass yc = new YourClass();
yc.Changed += SomeHandler;
```

? If you can produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, it will be a lot easier to diagnose.

Comment: thanks, will update above with the subscription... will try out a little demo app to replicate (Was just in a little panic with a deadline, but have taken out the feature now).

Comment: @Jon Skeet
Why must one have at least one handler attached to the event to trigger it ? A class may want to trigger it's event whenever it occurs, regardless of what is attached to it. I don't understand. Do you have to test for your event nullness everytime you want to trigger it ? Can't the handler list of the event just be emprty instead of the event being null itself ?

Comment: @Virus721 Because the designers of C# are incompetent. Imagine an empty list being represented as null ... what a botch that would be. Well, this is a botch of that sort. They turned Tony Hoare's billion dollar mistake into a billion and change.

Answer (score 3):

You must attach an event handler to the Changed event, only then will it not evaluate to null.

```
Changed += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("received Changed event");
if (Changed != null) Console.WriteLine("now Changed is not null");
```

Answer (score 2):

you missed this:

```
List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you assign a value, or more specifically, an eventhandler, to Changed anywhere? 
It should be null if it wasn't assigned a value...