# WPF C# PropertyChanged always null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, textblock

I have played around with this for a while and decided to see if someone can help, I have set in the constructor of StatusInfo the DataContext = this and didn't work.  When I write a string to ScreenStatusBarText it does call the OnPropertyChanged method but every time the PropertyChanged value is null.  I The status block I have at the bottom of the screen.  I have a tab section above this stack panel that has many components that use bindings and work.

Screen Code

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,1047,0,0">
  <Grid Name="StatusBarItemGrid">
  <TextBlock Name="StatusBarText" Text="may the force be with you"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
 </StackPanel>
```

Data Model:

```
public partial class StatusInfo :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string screenStatusBarText;

    public StatusInfo()
    {
        BindScreenStatusBarText();
        screenStatusBarText = "Initialized";
    }

    public string ScreenStatusBarText
    {
        get { return screenStatusBarText; }
        set
        {
            screenStatusBarText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StatusBarText");
        }
    }

    private void BindScreenStatusBarText()
    {

        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Source = screenStatusBarText;
        b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        b.Path = new PropertyPath("StatusBarText");
        MainWindow.mainWindow.StatusBarText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);

        MainWindow.mainWindow.StatusBarText.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    } 
}
```

My main :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static StatusInfo status;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceInitialized += MainWindow_SourceInitialized;
    }

    private void MainWindow_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetUpDisplay();
    }

    private void SetUpDisplay()
    {
            status = new StatusInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you reword _I have set in the constructor of StatusInfo the DataContext = this and didn't work._ its not clear to me

Comment: Why don't you just establish your bindings in XAML? Your approach looks, um, backward... That said, at first glance i see that you are not using the Binding.Source property correctly. See its documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn what the purpose of this property is. Also, your PropertyPath for the binding does not really match anything. You need to pay utmost attention if you want to insist on building/creating bindings in code-behind.

Comment: and i dont see where did you set DataContext ?

Comment: WPF/UWP and XAML were designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. This does not look like the MVVM pattern. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into issue at every other place. Years ago I wrote a short intro into MVVM: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf | Hopefully switching to it helps you.

Comment: Side note: in your setter, you might want to first do: `if (value == screenStatusBarText) return;`

Comment: public StatusInfo()
    {
        BindScreenStatusBarText();
        screenStatusBarText = "Initialized";
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Binding in XAML instead of code behind:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ScreenStatusBarText}" />
```

And use a view model like

```
public class StatusInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string screenStatusBarText = "Initialized";

    public string ScreenStatusBarText
    {
        get { return screenStatusBarText; }
        set
        {
            screenStatusBarText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ScreenStatusBarText));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

with an instance of the view model class assigned to the MainWindow's DataContext:

```
private readonly StatusInfo statusInfo = new StatusInfo();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = statusInfo;
}
```

You may now access the view model class at any time later, e.g. in an event handler of an element of MainWindow:

```
statusInfo.ScreenStatusBarText = "Something";
```

Comment: I have multiple tabs that each have multiple components on them.  using  DataContext = statusInfo; would mean that the next line would be DataContext = anothercomponent; how would I handle many components ?

Comment: Put a StatusInfo and other view model properties in an "outer" view model. Then bind like `Text="{Binding StatusInfo.ScreenStatusBarText}"`

Comment: Now it sometimes works but it isn't getting updated every time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You set ScreenStatusBarText, but the UI isn't updated?

Comment: Yes I set the ScreenStatusBarText to different values and it changes maybe one at of 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think your going to struggle doing your binding in code behind.

Having said that, with regards to why your `PropertyChanged` value is null. You've simply made a typo, as-is you're notifying subscribers that a property that doesn't exist has changed. One solution to avoid such typos is to use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof).

```
public string ScreenStatusBarText
{
    get { return screenStatusBarText; }
    set
    {
        screenStatusBarText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ScreenStatusBarText));
    }
}
```

It occurred to me you may also have meant that your event was null. This simply means you don't have any subscribers. See [Why is my "Event" always null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497317/why-is-my-event-always-null).

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null) // I have a subscriber.
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```